# function pointer and memory address in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, function-pointers

In the following program, `&foo`, `*foo` and `foo` points to the same memory adress :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int arg)
{
    printf("arg = %d\n", arg);
    return arg;
}

int main()
{
    foo(0); // ok
    (*foo)(0); // ok
    (&foo)(0); // ok

    printf("&foo = %lx\n", (size_t)(&foo));
    printf("foo = %lx\n", (size_t)(foo));
    printf("*foo = %lx\n", (size_t)(*foo));

    return 0;
}
```

the output is :

```
arg = 0
arg = 0
arg = 0
&foo = 55eeef54c720
foo = 55eeef54c720
*foo = 55eeef54c720
```

Does anyone can explain this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Function name (a sysmbol) is actually - a memory address it self. Liker change function name with the memory address when linking an executable. CPU instruction like `call foo` is a jump to the RAM block  where `foo` function CPU institutions (code) located.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the terminology of the C standard, any expression that has function type is a *function designator*. So, when used as an expression, the name of a function is a function designator.

There is nothing you can do with a function designator except take its address. You cannot add a number to a function designator, you cannot compare it to another function designator, and so on. Of course, you can call a function, but this is actually done by address, not by designator, as I will explain in a moment. Since there is nothing you can do with a function except take its address, C does this for you automatically. Per C 2018 6.3.2.1 4:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type "function returning type" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning type".

The result of this is:

- In `&foo`, the `&` takes the address of `foo`, so `&foo` is the address of `foo`.
- In `foo`, the function designator is automatically converted to the address of the function, so `foo` is `&foo`.
- In `*foo`, the function designator is automatically converted to the address of the function. Then the `*` operator converts this back to the function, which produces a function designator. Then the automatic conversion happens again, and the function designator is converted back to the address of the function, so the result of `*foo` is `&foo`.

When you call a function, using the `function ( argument-list... )` notation, the `function` must actually be a pointer to a function. Thus, you can call `foo` using `(&foo)(arguments...)`. The automatic conversion simplifies the syntax so you can write `foo(arguments...)`, but the call expression actually requires the address of the function, not the function designator.

Incidentally:

- A proper `printf` specifier for `size_t` values is `%zx`, not `%lx`.
- If you include `<stdint.h>`, it defines a type intended for converting pointers to integers, `uintptr_t`. This is preferably to converting pointers to `size_t`.

Answer (score 3):

The function `foo` is implicitly convertible to a pointer to the function `foo`.

The unary `&` applied to a function yields a pointer to the function, just like it yields the address of variable when applied to a variable.

The unary `*` applied to a function pointer, yields the pointed-to function, just like it yields the pointed-to variable when it is applied to an ordinary pointer to a variable.

So here, `foo` is the same as `&foo` which is the same as `*foo`.

So `*foo` is same as `*(&foo)` which is the same as `foo`.